# Array.fill() retaining previously selected months' dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have been looking around in SO and github for an explanation but couldn't find one. There've been many threads floating around with `Array.fill()` but nothing seems to answer my question.
So here it goes,

`const dates = Array(this.props.totalDays).fill().map((e, i) => moment(this.props.selectedDate).day(i+1).format('DD-MM'))`.

In the above statement `this.props.totalDays` is a number which is the number of days for the selected month. For example it'll be 31 starting January and 28, 31,30 as we select February, March and April respectively.
And `this.props.selectedDate` is a date in string format(for ex : 2018-01-01 for Jan, 2018-03-01 for March etc)

My `dates` array shows the dates in the required format when i select January as 01-01, 01-02, ......all the way till 01-31.

Now when i select February it messes up and i am not getting why?
When i select February my `dates` array will have the array starting from 01-29, 01-30, 01-31, 01-02....all the way till 25-02

And now when i select `March` the `dates` array is 26-02, 27-02, 28-02, 01-03,02-03......all the way till 28-03

I've been struggling to understand as to whats happening and have failed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Vikram

Comment: What is `this.props.selectedDate`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer : Sorry i missed out mentioning that, now i've edited the post.

Comment: COuld you add the code about selectedDate ? I suspect your problem comes from this value not being set to what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`moment.day()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) indicates the day of the week starting at 0 for Sunday. I think you want to set set the day of the month, which you get with [`date()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/).

```js
let totalDays = 28
let selectedDate = '2018-02-01'
const dates = Array(totalDays)
      .fill()
      .map((e, i) => 
         moment(selectedDate).date(i+1).format('MM-DD'))

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow!  I didn't know that day and date behave so differently. This explains why the dates were so random on selected dates anytime i would give it the first day of the month; if 1st was Wednesday, then it would pick from Sunday which would add days of the previous month. Thanks much. I couldn't figure it out as it wasn't following a pattern, it was totally random depending on the which day would be the 1st date of the month began from. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the impression that the fill() is the part causing issues.

In your example when you select February, you don't have the values you're expecting but you have an array with 28 elements.

Same thing when you select March, this time you do have 31 elements as expected.

Given the information in your description I'd say the problem is in this part of your code

```
moment(this.props.selectedDate).day(i+1).format('DD-MM')
```

What are you trying to do in the map function ? Are you just trying to fill the array with value like 01/02, 02/02, 03/02, ... ?

In this case you shouldn't use two different but strongly related variables. If you can have access to the selected month and selected year (for leap years) you could do this:

First add those two helper functions

```
const zeroPadIfNeeded = aValue => ('0' + aValue).slice(-2)
const daysInMonth = (aYear, aMonth) => new Date(aYear, aMonth, 0).getDate()
```

Then fill the dates array

```
let dates = new Array(daysInMonth(this.props.selectedYear, this.props.selectedMonth)).fill().map((e, i) => zeroPadIfNeeded(i + 1) + '-' + zeroPadIfNeeded(this.props.selectedMonth))
```

With selectedMonth starting from 1 for January.

As to your existing code to pinpoint where the issue is if you could share how you set the variable selectedDate as I strongly believe this is where your problems are coming from.

Comment: You are right, every time i select a different month, the array has as many elements as the number of days in that month, it's just that some days of the previous months are carried over. And to answer your question, yes i want to fill the array with the dates of the month starting from the 1st day till the last.
TBH, i am not able to figure out if the problem is with `fill()` or the way i'm trying to populate the array. :(

Comment: Fill is needed because the map function would not be called if you don't. You can either do `Array(number).fill().map(` or `[...Array(number)].map(`. I think Vikram should console.log `this.props.selectedDate` and see if/why it doesn't start with the first day of that month.

Comment: @HMR and Eponyme, thanks for the answers and help, i got a few things cleared today. :)